# Finding a table's row by some text it contains in column A, and selecting column B in the same row

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using casperjs.  There's a table on the current page, as shown below.  I have the string `"Title of Row 2 which I like"` and I'd like to search for the row in the table which contains this string.

Then click on the button in that row, namely `Clicky button 2`

```
<table>
    <!-- ...table header... -->
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Title of Row 1</td>
        <td>
            <button ... onClick='some javascript function'>Clicky Button 1</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row 2">
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Title of Row 2 which I like</td>
        <td>
            <button ... onClick='some javascript function'>Clicky button 2</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My ideas are:

1. I made a regular expression to search through the whole DOM for the whole row that has `"Title of Row 2 which I like"` to get the `id` of the row it's in.  Then with this I composed a selector, and found the button under that row.  I've done this and it's fine.

And that's about it for my ideas.  I'm just wondering, **is there a more *casper* (or *elegant*) way to do this?**  I had a look at some functions... nothing seems to be able to search for something by its text.  Thought something like `getElementsAttribute()` could get me the `id` of the row I'm looking for... but there's no way I could find the row.

Comment: I'm asking this question so that I can void doing so, buddy.

Comment: @ArtjomB. [Please stop linking to the “Zalgo” / anti-Cthulhu regex rant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261561/471272).  It doesn’t help anybody.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to achieve this easily. CasperJS provides the XPath utility:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
```

So you click the button like this:

```
casper.click(x("//tr[contains(td, 'Title of Row 2 which I like')]//button"));
```

This assumes that there is only one button per row. If the button is in the next `td` then you could use

```
casper.click(x("//tr/td[contains(., 'Title of Row 2 which I like')]/following-sibling::td[1]/button"));
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery, if you have it available, [has a selector that searches for DOM nodes by their text](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). To match your example above, you could use

> $( "td:contains('Title of Row 2 which I like')" )

Note that it's case-sensitive.

Comment: You forgot the clicking

Comment: @ArtjomB. Finding the DOM element was the problem at hand. It's an exercise for the reader to then do other things. Sure, right now he wants to click a button. But maybe tomorrow he wants to change the CSS of the parent row. But go ahead, downvote away.

Comment: Fine, I agree that using jQuery to find an element can be easily split from actually clicking, which is not easily possible with the casper way as different XPaths/CSS-selectors will be needed.

Comment: It's true that I wasn't asking about clicking; I know how to look up `click()` in the docs.  This is also a good solution, Artjom's is marginally less complicated though as I do not need JQuery.  I guess I need to read about XPath.